# How to convert unix timestamp into time based on a specific timezone?

Tags: java

I have a unix timestamp - 1449688800, and this timestamp is specific for timezone los angeles/california.

How can I convert this timestamp to timezone that is mentioned above in JAVA

Comment: Is that number already for the LA/Cali timezone or do you need to convert it? Because if it's UTC you can just subtract 8 hours from it and be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Java milliseconds is since Jan 1, 1970. [Unix time](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempo_(Unix)) is seconds since Jan 1, 1970, UTC (so if it is a unix time stamp it is from UTC, otherwise it is not a Unix time stamp (remove or add hours as needed))

The [time zone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) of Los Angeles is `TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")`

That lead us to

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
cal.setTimeInMillis(unixTime*1000);
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, amount of non corrisponding to unix timestamp from UTC);
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a certain time from an origin timezone to a target timezone:

```
public static long convertToTimeZone(long initialTime, TimeZone origin, TimeZone target)
{
    return initialTime + target.getRawOffset() - origin.getOffset(initialTime);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean result is java.Date object with angeles/california timezone?

Let's try, Convert your local timestamp to global timestamp then go create java.Date.

To convert to global you may need to calculate timezone offset.